# Диалоговое окно перед продолжением исполнения скрипта

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, проблема в следующем: после заполнения формы с полями и сабмита происходит поиск в бд. Если соответствующая запись не найдена, то должен появится диалог, запрашивающий подтверждение добавления соответствующей записи в бд. Если ответ "да" - добавить, если "нет" - остановить исполнение скрипта. Возможно ли реализовать подобное используя php средства?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, можно, алгоритм следующий: получаем данные, проверяем, если запись не найдена, отдаем форму с вопросом и с заполненными скрытыми полями, дублирующими первоначальный запрос. На кнопку "да" вешаем сабмит, на кнопку "нет" - переадресацию куда необходимо.